# JSON error text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 en JAVA

Tags: java, json, webservice, asp.net-web-api

Hola buenas tengo un problema con la web api al consumirla en la aplicación web JAVA.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema surge cuando llega a JSONobject, y no llega al System.print.out, saltando a la catch y presentando el problema **Grave:   org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]**

Al menos me lo registra en la BD de datos pero al caer al catch me devuelve mensajes de errores a la vista y no se como arreglarlo ya que no tengo conocimientos de JSON.

```java
 public JSONObject insertarCliente(Cliente c){
        //globalURL +=  "?rut=" + c.getRut() + "&nom="+ c.getNombre() +"&app=" + c.getApellidoP() + "&apm=" + c.getApellidoM();
        String globalURL = "http://localhost:60367/api/Cliente?rut=" + c.getRut() + "&nom="+ c.getNombre() +"&app=" + c.getApellidoP() + "&apm=" + c.getApellidoM();
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = Conectar(globalURL);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.getOutputStream().close();
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String resp = br.readLine();
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resp);
                System.out.println(obj);
                //JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(resp);
                br.close();
                return obj;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClienteDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Mensaje de error que me entrega:

```
Grave:   org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:432)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:184)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:310)
```

Comment: Cuando haces JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resp); la variable resp debe ser una String con un formato JSON válido, en tu caso, parece que esa String no comienza por el carácter '{', ¿Puedes mostrar que contiene esa String?

Comment: @jacdDev Solo me imprime un 1. No se si es porque el metodo del webservices devuelve un entero o no.

Comment: Pues ahí está el problema, intentas transformar la String "1" en un JSON. Tienes dos opciones, revisar el webservice si quieres que devuelva un JSON o manejar la salida de otra forma dependiendo de tus necesidades.

Comment: @jacdDev y será necesario pasar a un JSON para solo hacer el proceso de que registre y lo guarde a la BD, que donde estoy haciendo integración de sistemas con WEB API lo unico que me enseñaron fue con JSON pero igual no lo veo necesario, viendolo de ese punto de vista para registrar solamente.

Comment: No acabo de comprenderte, lo normal es que la conexión con la base de datos se haga en el servicio web, no en el Javascript. Lo que te está fallando es que el servicio web te está devolviendo "1", no es necesario que lo transformes a JSON si tu aplicación no lo necesita.

Answer (score 0):

El mismo mensaje de error indica el problema:

> Grave: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{'
> at 1 [character 2 line 1]

al recibir la respuesta de la consulta, estás usando la clase `JSONObject`, esta clase espera recibir un objeto json para procesar la información, recuerda

> Si el .json inicia con "{" se considera como objeto Json (Json
> Object).
>
> Si el .json inicia con "[" es considerado como Arreglo Json (Json
> Array).

revisa:
[Leer un json de un response en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/430901/leer-un-json-de-un-response-en-java/430908#430908)

Por lo tanto, el error indica "Un texto JSONObject debe comenzar con '{'", si no inicia con este carácter indica que no es un Objeto Json. Debes revisar la respuesta y asegurar que se esta entregando un objeto Json, en caso de recibir un arreglo json, revisa la respuesta que te sugiero revisar.