# Leer un json de un response en java

Tags: java, http, cliente

Estoy intentando leer un json que tiene unos datos a los cuales no se como ingresar o como leerlos en una lista para recorrer el array que viene dentro del json el problema es que el httpentity solo me deja usar en string `String apiOutput = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);` 
El data tiene las llaves [] lo que indica que eso va ser una lista pero no se como acceder a esos valores del data en el json

Response json.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "title_response": "Ok",
    "text_response": "Bancos consultados exitosamente",
    "last_action": "Query Bancos",
    "data": [
        {
            "bankCode": "0",
            "bankName":"A continuaci\ón seleccione su banco"
        },
        {
            "bankCode": "1022",
            "bankName": "Banco Union Colombiano"
        }
    ],
    "enpruebas": 2
}
```

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;



 DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("https://secure.payco.co/restpagos/pse/bancos.json?public_key=mikey");
            getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
            
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            String apiOutput = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            // Necesito acceder a los datos que tiene la data en el json que seria el siguiente y obtener en una lista los valores de bankCode y bankName.
            // [{"bankCode":"0","bankName":"A continuaci\\u00f3n seleccione su banco"},{"bankCode":"1022","bankName":"Banco Union Colombiano"}]
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(apiOutput);
            
            
            System.out.print("backname " + json.getString("bankName"));
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("ERROR" + e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa primeramente la respuesta, la respuesta Json puede ser de dos tipos:

> Si el .json inicia con "{" se considera como objeto Json (Json
> Object).
>
> Si el .json inicia con "[" es considerado como Arreglo Json (Json
> Array).

Por lo tanto la respuesta es un `JSONArray`:

```
[{"bankCode":"0","bankName":"A continuaci\\u00f3n seleccione su banco"},{"bankCode":"1022","bankName":"Banco Union Colombiano"}]
```

debes usar primeramente la clase `JSONArray` y posteriormente obtener la informaciòn de sus objetos:

```
    //JSONObject json = new JSONObject(apiOutput);
    JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(apiOutput);
    for(int i = 0;i< jarray.length(); i++ ){
        System.out.println("bankCode: " + jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("bankCode") + " bankName: " +jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("bankName"));
    }
```